# Microsoft Query Current Month

Tags: sql-server, excel

Sorry guys - new to this - complete novice.
I am pulling data from a SQL Server from Excel using Microsoft Query.
I'm currently limiting fields to just invoices within a date range using:

> =#10/1/2017# And <#10/31/2017#

My date format is:
2017-10-02 00:00:00.000

I run this report many times during the current month - so I need to change the string above when the new, current month, begins.

I'd love for someone to give me the command that will always pull the current month - regardless of the month - thus allowing me to not have to alter the condition when a new month begins.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you are in Excel you could try the TODAY() function.  =TODAY()  function?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The question is not so clear but here is what you can try with:

To find today with date and time:

```
=NOW()
```

To find the beginning of the month:

```
=EOMONTH(A2,-1)+1
```

To find the end of the month:

```
=EOMONTH(A2,0)
```

Let me know if this is what you are expecting.